# can i use mysql for django on appengine?

Tags: mysql, django, google-app-engine

Can i use mysql database connected to django application on for appengine paltform ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relational database is only available on their [business version](http://code.google.com/appengine/business/), google appengine uses google bigtable by default.

Since you're using django on appengine you might want to check out http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel for easier database handling if you find it too intimidating